# Question about reference letters on mathjobs

Tags: mathematics, career-path, job-search

I have a mechanical question about the mathjobs interface (I believe this is not off -topic since there is a correct answer and this answer would remove uncertainty for other mathematicians in future job cycles). If I list a reference letter in my application to a position, but the reference letter is submitted after the formal deadline (or at least after I submit the application), will that reference letter be automatically added to my dossier at the university in question or do I have to re-submit all of my materials?

Answer (score 3):

The reference letter is automatically added to your applications by mathjobs when it is uploaded by your letter-writers, and there is no need to resubmit.

However, I recommend sending gentle reminders to your letter-writers!

Comment: The reference letter is automatically added to the file at mathjobs.org.  However, if someone has downloaded an earlier version of the application, they may not see the new/updated letter of recommendation.

Comment: Thanks Brian and Aru. @Brian Borchers, do you have any tip about what I could do to deal with this potential problem? I've already put in my cover letter who my recommenders are.

Comment: I'm afraid that there's nothing you can do about this if someone has downloaded an application from the mathjobs.org site.